# VS 2017 Design-Time Error

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2017, design-time

I have commented on other posts regarding this, in the hope of getting an answer.

I'm a teacher and we use VB in Years 10,11 and 12. Since we upgraded to VS2017 we have had the repeated problem of not being able to re-edit our Design Forms after the project has been shut down. The program will still run, but we can't access the Design view of the form.

We have gone back to VS 2013 which does not have this problem.

Our deveopment process is this:

1. Create new Project
2. Add new Name and Identify Location
3. Create the Interface using Toolbox and Properties Windows
4. Write Code
5. Run and check

I have found each time in VS 2017 we get the error (see image attached below) every time in VS2017. We do not edit the Design code, yet the error includes objects not being defined when they are all named. The program is a very basic demo that reads in two numbers and adds them.

I'm wondering if the version of VS2017 is in error or needs to be re-installed, or if my method of development (listed above) is now in error with VS2017.

Here is the development process for this little program demo:

Created a basic interface with two textboxes called txtNum1 & txtNum2, a label lblAnswer and a button(btncalc). 
I then double clicked on the button and typed the following:

```
Public Class Form1 
  Private Sub btncalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btncalc.Click 

   Dim intNum1 As Integer 
   Dim intNum2 As Integer 
   Dim intAnswer As Integer 

   intNum1 = txtNum1.Text 
   intNum2 = txtNum2.Text 
   intAnswer = intNum1 + intNum2 
   lblAnswer.Text = intAnswer 

 End Sub 
End Class
```

Screen grab of error:

[image: Screen grab of error]

Comment: You are making undisclosed changes to a working project. Unless you explain, in detail, what you are doing, we can offer nothing more than speculation.

Comment: Created a basic interface with two textboxes called txtNum1 & txtNum2, a label lblAnswer and a button(btncalc). I then double clicked on the button and typed the following: Public Class Form1
    Private Sub btncalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btncalc.Click
        Dim intNum1 As Integer
        Dim intNum2 As Integer
        Dim intAnswer As Integer
        intNum1 = txtNum1.Text
        intNum2 = txtNum2.Text
        intAnswer = intNum1 + intNum2
        lblAnswer.Text = intAnswer
    End Sub
End Class

Comment: I can't believe I am the only person experiencing this problem.

Comment: Maybe link the entire project somewhere so we can see if it happens to us, too.

Comment: You'll have to believe it, just you.  Nothing that a disk reformat could not fix, doing anything less drastic does not come with a similar warranty.

Comment: Your screenshot is not visible.  Can  you please edit your question to include the text of the error message.  That would be useful to future users.  Images cannot be searched.

Comment: I have had Admin reinstall the VS Community on both my machine and on the desktops for the students and the problem has been eliminated. Thank you to everyone who gave me a hand with this!